# salesforce developer - SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org

Tags: salesforce, lwc

I have Lightning Web Components called list.
And when I try to do `SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org`,
To get my classes from Apex class.
I get the following error:

> 20:32:09.428 Starting `SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org`
> === Retrieve Warnings
> FULL NAME  TYPE                      MESSAGE
> ─────────  ────────────────────────  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> list       LightningComponentBundle  Entity of type 'LightningComponentBundle' named 'list' cannot be found
> 20:32:10.344 ended SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org

I need help,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new project with the command:

```
SFDX: Create Project with Manifest
```

Then, I right-clicked on the `package.xml` file in the `manifest` folder,
and selected:

```
SFDX: Retrieve Source in Manefist from Org
```

This worked.

Answer (score 0):

(not a real answer but too long for a comment)

What's the exact command you're running to fetch it. If the command you run doesn't explicitly mention username/alias - check what happens when you open the default org (`sfdx force:org:open`) - by using default org you might be connecting to wrong org and the component really isn't there.

Maybe "list" is a reserved keyword?

Can you definitely see the component in the org. Setup -> Lightning Components contains it? When you open the developer console, query (tick the "Tooling API" checkbox at the bottom!) and run

```
SELECT Id, FilePath, Format, Source 
FROM LightningComponentResource
ORDER BY FilePath
```

Is the component in there somewhere? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_lightningcomponentresource.htm

Do you have other tools available like Ant + Migration tool or even [Workbench](http://workbench.developerforce.com/). You should be able to run a full metadata retrieve with package.xml similar to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>LightningComponentBundle</name>
    </types>
    <version>52.0</version>
</Package>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your question there might be possible these issues:

1- When you authorize your org with VS code then might be possible your org is different and when you retrieve that is different.

2- When you deploy your code after that can be possible you delete that file, then this error can be shown.

I hope you find the above solution helpful. If it does, please mark it as the Best Answer to help others too.

Thanks and Regards,
Suraj Tripathi